# Access data entry scrolling buttons

Tags: ms-access

I created a form in ACCESS based on previously created table that was empty. Before any cosmetic changes to the form I was able to add records, and using the little < > buttons at the bottom of the form, I was able to scroll through the data in the table.  I then made some cosmetic changes, changed the tab order, and now the scrolling buttons don't work.  Are they supposed to work on a data entry form, or do I need to add controls for scrolling.

Comment: Should work. Hard to say what is causing issue without reviewing form. Might post to a forum that allows attaching files and provide yours for analysis. Did you set form DataEntry property to Yes? This will not retrieve existing records but should be able to navigate new records created during a session. Every time form is closed then opened is a new session.

Comment: Form data property is set to yes.  Do you mean that after a session is closed the previously entered data is not available?

Comment: That is correct. Data Entry set to Yes means form set to only receive new record input, not display existing. Any records entered in a session can be navigated but not records created prior.

Comment: That clears that up.  thanks